# Deprecation warning: explicitly call ax.remove() as needed

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code that works correctly for me with `matplotlib==3.8.2`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Random data
r = np.random.randn(1000)
theta = np.random.randn(1000)

fig = plt.figure()

# Ignore all other subplots for MWE
# ...

axc = plt.subplot(236)
ax = plt.subplot(236, projection='polar')
ax.set(xticklabels=[], yticklabels=[])
ax.grid(False)
hist, phi_edges, r_edges = np.histogram2d(theta, r, bins=50)
axc.set_xlim(-r_edges[-1], r_edges[-1])
axc.set_ylim(-r_edges[-1], r_edges[-1])
X, Y = np.meshgrid(phi_edges, r_edges)
pc = ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, hist.T)
cbar = plt.colorbar(pc, ax=[axc, ax], location='right')
cbar.set_label("Counts", rotation=270, labelpad=15)

plt.show()
```

But it fails using `matplotlib==3.7.5` with:

```
/path/to/scripts/./bin/program.py:108: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Auto-removal of overlapping axes is deprecated since 3.6 and will be removed two minor releases later; explicitly call ax.remove() as needed.
  ax = plt.subplot(236, projection="polar")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/scripts/./bin/program.py", line 113, in <module>
    cbar = fig.colorbar(pc, ax=[ax, axc], location="right")
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/path/to/scripts/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1300, in colorbar
    cax, kwargs = cbar.make_axes(ax, **kwargs)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/path/to/scripts/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 1434, in make_axes
    raise ValueError('Unable to create a colorbar axes as not all '
ValueError: Unable to create a colorbar axes as not all parents share the same figure.
```

I need my script to run with python 3.8.0 and that is why I now need it to run with matplotlib 3.7.5. Can someone suggest how to get this working? I have tried to `ax.remove()` and `plt.clf()` before my second axis, but of course that is not working because I need both axes to draw the colorbar where I need it.

Comment: you are mixing using functions called from `plt` and the object-oriented approach (functions called from `fig`, `ax`, etc.). I would suggest switching to always called from `fig`, `ax`, `axc` etc., to make sure you are always interacting with the object you are expecting to.

For example, use `fig.add_subplot()` instead of `plt.subplot()`, and `fig.colorbar` instead of `plt.colorbar`. 

Also note, the deprecation warning is just a warning, and not related to your error here.

Comment: @tmdavison Thanks, you were right. Your changes fixed my issues. What in the error message suggests that this was the issue?

Comment: `not all parents share the same figure` was the clue that something was happening on the wrong instance somewhere. It's a common mistake people make to mix the two conventions.